# Element 'resource', attribute 'module': The attribute 'module' is not allowed

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes, error

I tried to login to my admin backend, but this problem always occurs:

```
Element 'resource', attribute 'module': The attribute 'module' is not allowed.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the attribute name..It may be used by some other functions..